# show limit does not exists with 2 variables

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

[image]

How can I prove that the limit in any (x0,x0) does not exits?
I tried to find 2 curves but I don't know how to choose them.

Comment: Which limit do you speak about.

Comment: Try setting $x=1$ and taking the limit as $y$ approaches 1, and then setting $y=1$ and taking the limit as $x$ approaches 1

Comment: Do you perhaps mean to look at the limit as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$?  As $(x,y)\to (1,1)$?  Or perhaps somewhere else?

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah   OP states "the limit in any (x0,x0)".

Answer (score 0):

In 2-dimensional space, one reason a limit wouldn't exist is if the value as you approach from one direction is different from the value as you approach from another direction. For instance Limit 1/x as x->0.  Negative values close to zero will be very negative and positive values close to 0 will be very positive, so it doesn't exist.

You get the same effect in your problem.  If x is slightly larger than y, then x-y is positive.  If x is slightly smaller than y, then x-y is negative.  These slight changes will not be enough to flip the numerator from positive to negative, so you'll have huge negative numbers on one side of y=x and huge positives on the other.

The only place you may not be able to use that argument is near where x and y are close to zero. By experimentally plugging in values, it still seems to hold true.  I guess no matter how small the numerator is, the limit of the denominator gets infinitely closer to 0 than that, so you still have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Limit in $(x_0,x_0)\neq(0,0).$

Consider $x=y-h$ with $h\to 0$ and fix $y\neq 0.$ Along this path, $$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{(y-h)^2\cdot y}{h}$$ does not exist.